# Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value. What does this error message mean?

Tags: html, xml, soap

I get this error message:

"Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php on line 76 "

The code on line 76:

```
$GLOBALS['_transient']['static']['nusoap_base']->globalDebugLevel = 9;
```

What does this mean? And how can I fix it.

Looking forward to your reply

Regards

SirBT

Answer (score 1):

You can set the error_reporting level to strict just before include nusoap library:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_STRICT);
require 'nusoap.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing the nusoap.php file with a an older version specifically nusoap.php 0.95.

The PHP environment I work in is: PHP 5.3.8, nusoap.php 0.95 seems to be compatible with PHP 5.3.8. My conclusion is that the: "Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php on line 76" is a compatibility issue.